# UTM ubuntu linux installation says "network is unreachable"

Tags: virtualization

I installed this program called UTM for virtualization. I then installed ubuntu OS there as explained in this guide https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/ubuntu-20-04

But the network doesn't work there, when I do `ping google.com` it says "Network is unreachable".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow the official ubuntu installation guide from here https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/ubuntu-20-04 the Network Mode setting will be "Shared Network". [image]

I changed it to "Emulated VLAN" and everything started working.[image]